# What's the difference between globals $base_root and $base_url

Tags: 6

Can't seem to find the difference between these.  D6 is what I need to know, but would love to know how those looks into 7 and even 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`$base_root`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_root/6) is:

> The root URL of the host, excluding the path.

e.g. http://localhost

[`$base_url`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_url/6) is:

> The base URL of the drupal installation.

again, e.g. http://localhost

The only situation I can think of where these would be different is if your Drupal installation is in a sub-folder of the web root. In that case `$base_url` would also contain the sub-folder in the path, e.g. http://localhost/drupal

The descriptions in the documentation are exactly the same for both across versions 6, 7 and 8.